# Why onPrepareOptionsMenu cannot resolve method findItem on Android

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-menu

I am trying to enable or disable a menu Item and I use the following:

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
{

    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_stats_undo);

    if (PlayerListSelect==1) {
        item.setEnabled(true);
        item.getIcon().setAlpha(255);
    } else {
        // disabled
        item.setEnabled(false);
        item.getIcon().setAlpha(130);
    }
    return true;
}
```

And

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.stats_menu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

and the XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_stats_undo"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="UNDO"/>
</menu>
```

but I get a red color findItem , Cannot resolve method why?

Comment: do you have this item "menu_stats_undo" in your xml file?

Comment: post your menu.xml file and also the code where you inflate it in your activity/fragment

Comment: post the menu xml and you cant set visibility invisible or gone

Comment: @DAgrawal we can set the visibility through this tag setVisible(true/false);

Comment: Which `Menu` class do you have imported? Are you getting a warning about the override?

Comment: @MikeM you mean R.menu.stats_menu

Comment: No, I mean the `Menu` class in your `import` statements at the top of the file.

Comment: There is not any particular class imported about menu

Comment: OK, just change the `onPrepareOptionsMenu()` method's parameter type `android.view.Menu`. That is, `public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu menu)`. Or add the `import android.view.Menu;`.

Comment: Yes that was it, but why?

Comment: The `Menu` specified in the `onPrepareOptionsMenu()` method's parameter was the wrong class. You either have another class named `Menu` in your project, or you have one imported that you're not noticing. Your IDE should've been complaining about the method not overriding a method in the super class, too.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
{
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.YOUR_MENU_FILE_NAME, menu);
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_stats_undo);

    if (PlayerListSelect==1) {
        item.setEnabled(true);
        item.getIcon().setAlpha(255);
    } else {
        // disabled
        item.setEnabled(false);
        item.getIcon().setAlpha(130);
    }
    return true;
}
```